# CSS - Como manipular Div's?

Tags: css, html5

Estou estuando div's e estou com dificuldade em alinhar as div's da maneira que preciso, como na seguinte imagem : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém está ficando da seguinte forma :

```css
#total { 
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

#pequeno { 
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
}

#maior { 
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="total"> 
    <div id="pequeno"> </div>
    <div id="maior"></div>
</div>
```

Podem me ajudar??

Comment: Atualmente, existem técnicas melhores para posicionamento de elemento. Eu diria para você utilizar `float` em casos muito específicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom amigo, coloque o seguinte codigo em seu css:

```css
#pequeno {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    
#maior {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
```

Explicação, ao utiliza a propriedade "POSITION: RELATIVE", você poderá manipular livremente a "DIV", usando no caso "TOP e LEFT" para definir os valores.

Comment: Aaah sim, entendi, qual a diferença da position:relative para o clear??

Comment: o clear, assim como você comentou faz o gerenciamento automático da posição, enquanto que com relative você tem a opção de escolher exatamente onde vai ficar.

Comment: Lembrando que seria melhor usar o sistema de "%" em vez de "px" para que seu site/app se adapte aos diferentes tamanhos de monitores.

Comment: Certo !!, obrigado pela dica Diego !!

Comment: Disponha, sua duvida me ajudou também, afinal eu tive que pesquisar para responde-la kkk

Answer (score 3):

Apenas adicione no css do #maior o 'clear:right'

```css
   #total { 
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
   }
   #pequeno { 
    background-color:yellow;
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:60px;
   }
   #maior { 
    background-color:blue;
                clear: right;
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
    <div id="total"> 
   <div id="pequeno"> </div>
   <div id="maior"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wooow, perfeito !! não sabia deste comando, ele joga tudo ao extremo right ??

Answer (score 2):

Faltou um `clear:both` na div `#maior`

```css
#total { 
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
   }
   #pequeno { 
    background-color:yellow;
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:60px;
   }
   #maior { 
    background-color:blue;
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
        clear: both;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
    <div id="total"> 
   <div id="pequeno"> </div>
   <div id="maior"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deu certo!! o que faz este comando clear??

Comment: A propriedade clear é importante para controlar o comportamento de elementos flutuantes. Você limpa a propriedade flutuante do elemento.

Comment: obrigado Diego !!

Answer (score -1):

```css
#total {
  background-color: red;
  width: 265px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#pequeno {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#maior {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#cuerpo {
  background-color: #FEF8E2;
  float: left;
  width: 260px;
  height: 160px;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="total">
    <div id="pequeno"> Pequeño </div>
    <div id="maior"> Mayor </div>
    <div id="pequeno"> Pequeño </div>
    <div id="maior"> Mayor </div>
    <div id="cuerpo"> Cuerpo </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```